# Array as structure members Assignment Student Test Scores

Tags: vb.net

ASSIGNMENT
A teacher has six students and wants you to create an application that stores their grade data in a file and prints a grade report. The application should have a structure that stores the following student data: Name (a string), Test Scores (an array of five Doubles), and Average (a Double). Because the teacher has six students, the application should use an array of six structure variables.
The application should allow the user to enter data for each student, and calculate the average test score. 
The user should be abled to save the data to a file, read the data from the file, and print a report showing each student's test scores and average score. The form shows a meny system. You may you buttons instead if you prefer.
Input validation: Do not accept test scores less that zero or greater than 100.

[image: Form]

]

my understanding of how it should be structured 
[image]

For the Moment I don't understand that in the FOR EACH loop I can not accumulate total it saying that I am not allowed to use + . I am trying to get scores from txtScore1Std1 (For example) assign it to dblTestScoreArray and using for each loop to find sum of those 5 score and when find average and output it to lbl average for student number 1.

Code Module:

```
 Module StudentTestScoresModule

    Const intMAX_SUBSCRIPT_STUDENT As Integer = 6
    Const intMAX_SUBSCRIPT_STUDENT_SCORES As Integer = 5
   'create structure
    Public Structure StudentData
       Dim strName As String
       Dim dblTestScoresArray() As Double
       Dim dblAverage As Double
    End Structure

Dim dblTotalStd1 As Double
Dim dblScore As Double

Dim StudentsArray(intMAX_SUBSCRIPT_STUDENT) As StudentData

Sub StudentNameDataInput()
    StudentsArray(0).strName = MainForm.txtStdName1.Text
    StudentsArray(1).strName = MainForm.txtStdName2.Text
    StudentsArray(2).strName = MainForm.txtStdName3.Text
    StudentsArray(3).strName = MainForm.txtStdName4.Text
    StudentsArray(4).strName = MainForm.txtStdName5.Text
    StudentsArray(5).strName = MainForm.txtStdName6.Text
End Sub

Sub StudentScoreDataInput()
    For intIndex = 0 To intMAX_SUBSCRIPT_STUDENT
        ReDim StudentsArray(intIndex).dblTestScoresArray(4)
    Next
    'test scores for first student
    StudentsArray(0).dblTestScoresArray(0) = CDbl(MainForm.txtScore1Std1.Text)
    StudentsArray(1).dblTestScoresArray(1) = CDbl(MainForm.txtScore2Std1.Text)
    StudentsArray(2).dblTestScoresArray(2) = CDbl(MainForm.txtScore3Std1.Text)
    StudentsArray(3).dblTestScoresArray(3) = CDbl(MainForm.txtScore4Std1.Text)
    StudentsArray(4).dblTestScoresArray(4) = CDbl(MainForm.txtScore5Std1.Text)

    For Each i As StudentData In StudentsArray
        dblTotalStd1 += i
    Next
    dblAverage = dblTotalStd1 / intMAX_SUBSCRIPT_STUDENT_SCORES
    MainForm.lblAvgStd1.Text = (dblAverage.ToString)
End Sub

Sub CalculateAverage()
End Sub

End Module
```

Code Main Form:

```
 Public Class MainForm

Private Sub mnuHelpAbout_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles mnuHelpAbout.Click
    'about program
    MessageBox.Show("Student test score calculator version 0.1")
End Sub

Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
    ' Close(program)
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
    StudentScoreDataInput()
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Tell your teacher that mutable (data can be changed) structures are bad.

Comment: well can't do that at list now, but thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just by looking, without testing, what you need to do is;

```
'untested code
For Each i As StudentData In StudentsArray
    For Each S as Double in i.dblTestScoresArray
        dblTotalStd1 += s
    Next
Next
```

you cannot do += on a structure, you need to do it on the member and since its an array, you need to loop through it